# Error after adding firebase_auth to flutter app

Tags: flutter, firebase

i've added firebase_auth and get this error

```
 CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.0.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.0.0) was resolved to 10.0.0, which depends on
        FirebaseAuth (~> 10.0.0) was resolved to 10.0.0, which depends on
          GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 2.1)

    mobile_scanner (from `.symlinks/plugins/mobile_scanner/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning (~> 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
        MLKitBarcodeScanning (~> 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.0, which depends on
          MLKitVision (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
            GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
```

if i remove the firebase_auth, everything goes fine .
i've tried to use arch -x86_64 pod install with no success .
any one faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `Podile.lock` and rebuild the app

**UPDATE**

Sometimes problems happen due target ios platform. Try to do these steps:

- flutter clean
- update all dependencies to the latest version in `pubspec.yml` file and do `flutter pub get`
- Go to your `Podfile` and uncomment `#platform :ios, '9.0'` Then change the version to 10 `platform :ios, '10.0'`
- go to **ios** folder and throuh the terminal run command: `pod repo update`, `pod update` or `pod install`

Comment: i have, With no use

Comment: try to use updated approach

Comment: same thing , same problem

Answer (score 0):

Both the packages ([firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) and [mobile_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/mobile_scanner)) are using [GTMSessionFetcher](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GTMSessionFetcher) pod internally in iOS.

As both plugin uses different version of [GTMSessionFetcher](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GTMSessionFetcher) it causes conflicts, thus we are not able to compile iOS app.

There is one open [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10359) in firebase-ios-sdk where we can get all the updates, as of now I am also not able to found any issues, but will update here if I found anything important. Thanks.

Update

I found two more linked issues.

[Issue 1](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues/357)

[Issue 2](https://github.com/bharat-biradar/Google-Ml-Kit-plugin/issues/333)

Answer (score 0):

For me Updating all the firebase dependencies to the latest version and google sign in version removed this error.

Then, run pod install.